# Is there a way to override id for disabled options in a select before submitting the form in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to disable the options inside the dropdown for archived records and want to know is there a way to override the id/ send value to the form before submitting. I have 2 dropdown which uses the same id and while editing the form for already disabled records(in the 2nd dropdown), id is getting passed from the 1st dropdown since the disabled record will not be sent.How to override this id while submitting the form?

```
<div class="field">
    <%= form.label :discrepancy_id, 'Discrepancy Category' %>
    <%= form.select :discrepancy_id, Discrepancy.get_first_category_details, {include_blank: "Select the Discrepancy category....." , :selected => (@fault.id.nil?) ? nil : Fault.selectedCategory(@fault.discrepancy_id)},:class => 'failure-category', :required => true%>
  </div>

<div class="field" data-target="fault.discrepancyContainer">
    <%= form.label :discrepancy_id, 'Discrepancy Name' %>
    <%= form.select :discrepancy_id, grouped_options_for_select(Discrepancy.get_grouped_names_based_on_category, {:selected => @fault.discrepancy_id, :disabled => Discrepancy.get_archived_entries}), {include_blank: "Select the Discrepancy Name....."}, :class => 'failure-mode', :required => true %>
  </div>
```

Comment: When you say the dropdowns use the same ID, you mean their HTML element has the same ID? Or the options they show have the same ID in your database?

Comment: Its the HTML Element ( id : :discrepancy_id)

Comment: It's pretty fundamental to have elements each having a unique ID.. while I know it's not what you asked I'd strongly suggest changing that if it's causing you problems instead of coding around it

Comment: Just add a custom ID to your second dropdown which should fix your issue

Comment: Sorry! Both refers to the same table and id is coming from database. But both refers to different id , and second one overrides the first id . But when an option is disabled, id from 1st drop down updates the database which I want to override it 2nd drop down . Is there a way to do it?